# Javascript JSON and WCF webservice on Phonegap Android

Tags: android, json, wcf, cordova

I'm trying to run this code to call a WCF function from a phonegap application on Android

I tested the webservice using POSTER from firefox and can get through just fine, and returns the correct values (actually it only returns true or false)

```
function verifyAccount(username, password){
   $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url:  "http://50.63.174.229/banknoteservice/service1.svc/verifyAccount",
    data:  JSON.stringify("{'username' : 'test' , 'password' : 'test'}"),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {    
        $("#myDiv").html(msg);
    },
    error: function(e){
        $("#myDiv").html('error');              
    }
});
```

}

Every time I try to run it on the phone, it shows the error message in the div

Comment: What's your service definition? What is the value of the error?

Comment: Have you seen what kind of error is happening? Can you validate that the request is making it to the server? If it is, can you see if there is any server side error?

Comment: @NickRoth I edited the question, yes the function works on the server

Comment: Did you get any more information on what kind of error is happening? Instead of filling #myDiv with a simple static message, try printing information from e to give you an indication about what is going wrong.

Comment: @NickRoth That's one of the things I can't do, how would I print the error message?